# Unable to start after stop the application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

- I have a little application contains a start and reset button in this
  timer alike program.
- In the button start event handler, I have a FileSystemWatcher and Timer
  to call a function at certain time.
- I also have another timer to count down the time call `timerCounter` just to do for visual aid.
- What I want is to click the start button again to run the program
  after the stop/reset button is clicked, but fail to do so.

[image]

Below is my part of the code that I have doubt how to restart the program again on the `start button` click event.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // file system watcher, timer and one other function inside this event handler

  _timeLeft = (int)numUpDown.Value;     
  timerCounter.Start();
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _timer.Stop();
  timerCounter.Stop();
  _timer.Dispose();
  numUpDown.Value = 0;
  timeLabel.Text = 0 + @" seconds";
  lblResult.Text = @"Program has stopped, press start button to 
  process again.";
  _fsw.Dispose();
}

private void timerCounter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (_timeLeft > 0)
  {
    _timeLeft = _timeLeft - 1;
    timeLabel.Text = _timeLeft + " seconds";
    lblResult.Text = $@"Process began and counting down {timeLabel.Text} in seconds";
  }
   else
   {
     timerCounter.Stop();
     timerCounter.Enabled = false;
     timeLabel.Text = $@"Time's up";
   }
}
```

Comment: By "program" do you mean the FileSystemWatcher? If so, instead of disposing of it in the stop method, set [EnableRaisingEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.7.2) to `false` instead, and don't dispose the timer: then you can re-enable FSW events in the start method.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks! It's now can switch the state, but Wonder why can't dispose of the stop method as it helps to release memory. Please advise.

Comment: You don't **want** to release the memory until you're done with the control - and anyway it will be released automatically when your form closes.

Comment: Although it looks working, once I started the timer again and put the new folder in but it never zip that folder. I wonder why.